# How prove this $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\sin{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sin{\left(\frac{3\pi-1}{4}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\sin{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sin{\left(\frac{3\pi-1}{4}\right)}$$

I have some question. Using [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7Dsinxsin%28sqrt%28x%29%29dx), find this integral is not converge, I'm wrong?

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First make the substitution $x=u^2$ to get:

$\displaystyle \int _{0}^{\infty }\!\sin \left( x \right) \sin \left( \sqrt {x}
 \right) {dx}=\int _{0}^{\infty }\!2\,\sin \left( {u}^{2} \right) \sin
 \left( u \right) u{du}$,

$\displaystyle=-\int _{0}^{\infty }\!u\cos \left( u \left( u+1 \right)  \right) {du}+
\int _{0}^{\infty }\!u\cos \left( u \left( u-1 \right)  \right) {du}$,

and changing variable again in the second integral on the R.H.S such that $u\rightarrow u+1$ this becomes:

$=\displaystyle\int _{0}^{\infty }\!-u\cos \left( u \left( u+1 \right)  \right) {du}+
\int _{-1}^{\infty }\!\left(u+1\right)\cos \left( u \left( u+1 \right)  \right) {du}
$,

$\displaystyle=\int _{0}^{\infty }\!\cos \left( u \left( u+1 \right)  \right) {du}+
\int _{-1}^{0}\! \left( u+1 \right) \cos \left( u \left( u+1 \right) 
 \right) {du}
$.

Now we write $u=v-1/2$ and this becomes:

$\displaystyle\int _{1/2}^{\infty }\!\cos \left( {v}^{2}-1/4 \right) {dv}+\int _{-1/
2}^{1/2}\! \left( v+1/2 \right) \cos \left( {v}^{2}-1/4 \right) {dv}=$

$\displaystyle \left\{\int _{0}^{\infty }\!\cos \left( {v}^{2}-1/4 \right) {dv}\right\}$

$\displaystyle  +\left\{\int _{-1/2}
^{1/2}\!v\cos \left( {v}^{2}-1/4 \right) {dv}+\int _{-1/2}^{0}\!1/2\,
\cos \left( {v}^{2}-1/4 \right) {dv}-1/2\,\int _{0}^{1/2}\!\cos
 \left( {v}^{2}-1/4 \right) {dv}\right\},$

but the second curly bracket is zero by symmetry and so:

$\displaystyle \int _{0}^{\infty }\!\sin \left( x \right) \sin \left( \sqrt {x}
 \right) {dx}=\displaystyle \int _{0}^{\infty }\!\cos \left( {v}^{2}-1/4 \right) {dv}$,

$\displaystyle =\int _{0}^{
\infty }\!\cos \left( {v}^{2} \right) {dv}\cos \left( 1/4 \right) +
\int _{0}^{\infty }\!\sin \left( {v}^{2} \right) {dv}\sin \left( 1/4
 \right) 
$.

We now quote the limit of Fresnel integrals:

$\displaystyle\int _{0}^{\infty }\!\cos \left( {v}^{2} \right) {dv}=\int _{0}^{
\infty }\!\sin \left( {v}^{2} \right) {dv}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$,

to obtain:

$\displaystyle \int _{0}^{\infty }\!\sin \left( x \right) \sin \left( \sqrt {x}
 \right) {dx}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)+\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sin{\left(\dfrac{3\pi-1}{4}\right)}$.

Comment: When you replace *one* of $u$ by $u+1$, you changed the way how $u$ goes to infinity, so this result does not conflict my assertion.

Comment: Could you be more specific, I let $u\rightarrow u+1$ in only the right integral in the third line simply because it is a dummy variable; that is, it is unrelated to the other integral. How has the way it goes to infinity changed? Why does that effect the result?

Comment: Let $F(u)=A(u)+B(u)=\int_0^u (a+b)$, when you replace $u$ by $u+1$ in $b$, what basically you obtain is $F_1(u)=A(u)+B(u+1)$. If $A$ and $B$ both converges then this doesn't matter.

Comment: So are you saying that the OP is wrong or right?

Comment: Thank you @GrahamHesketh,It's very nice!

Comment: @Ma Ming in the example you give you appear to be talking about functions of $u$, i.e. $u$ is a free variable appearing as an upper limit. In the integral that I am manipulating $u$ is a dummy variable inside the integral and is integrated out; all I did was rename it (although I still used "$u$" so I could combine it with the other integral). Perhaps you take issue with where I effectively used $\infty-1=\infty$ in the upper limit, is that what you mean?

Comment: This is justified if we understand the integrals as Abel sums.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh What you need to verify is $A(u)$ and $B(u)$ both converge (at least one), then you will get $\lim_{u\to\infty}F(u)=\lim_{u\to\infty}A(u)+\lim_{u\to\infty}B(u)=\lim_{u\to \infty} A(u)+\lim_{u\to\infty}B(u+1)$. Otherwise, I suppose one can produce any value as the result.

Comment: As I said before, I don't see why you are writing functions of $u$ when this is simply a dummy variable and is being integrated out. I am saying this: Consider $\int_{a}^{b}f(u){du}=\int_{a-1}^{b-1}f(v+1){dv}$, I can't see you would have any issue here as I just renamed the variable. Now I am saying that as $b\rightarrow\infty$, $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(u){du}=\int_{a-1}^{\infty}f(v+1){dv}$ and as far as I can tell, either neither the left or right side converges, or if the left converges to L so does the right.

Comment: An integral with upper bound $\infty$ is a *limit* of finite integrals. The finite integrals we are taking a limit of we can interpret as a function of whatever the upper bound is, that upper bound being a variable going off to $\infty$. You will notice for example that $\int^\infty \cos(u(u+1))udu$ *definitely* does not converge in the ordinary sense. But when you interpret things as say $\int^U\square du+\int^U\square du$ as $U\to\infty$ in the 2nd line of this answer, it is sensible, and convergence-wise it is not justified to shift one function of $U$ but not the other inside the limit.

Comment: For example, $$\begin{array}{ll} 0 & = \int_0^\infty 0du \\ & =\int_0^\infty 1du+\int_0^\infty -1du \\ & = \int_{-1}^\infty1du+\int_0^\infty -1du \\ & = \int_{-1}^01du+\int_0^\infty(1-1)du \\ & = 1\end{array}$$ hence $0=1$, would be the result of a similar computation.

Comment: I would recommend this answer is not accepted because I acknowledge the comments above, I would delete it if the system would let me.

Answer (score 11):

Numerical calculation shows that the graph of

$$ y = \int_{0}^{x} \sin t \sin \sqrt{t} \, dt $$

is given by

[image]

Though a graph cannot constitute a proof, it strongly suggests that $y$ cannot converge as $x \to \infty$. Indeed, we can show that

$$ y(x) = -\cos x \sin \sqrt{x} + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sin \left( \frac{3\pi - 1}{4} \right) + o(1) $$

as $x \to \infty$. Thus in ordinary sense, the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x \sin \sqrt{x} \, dx $$

diverges. But if we understand the integral in Abel summation senas as follows

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x \sin \sqrt{x} \, dx := \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \int_{(0, \infty)} \sin x \sin \sqrt{x} \; e^{-sx} \, dx, $$

then the oscillating part vanishes and we obtain the identity. In fact, it converges to the proposed limit as weak as in Cesaro summation sense.

Now let us show that the integral converges in Able summation sense. By some calculation, we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x \sin \sqrt{x} \; e^{-sx} \, dx
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} 2x \sin x \sin (x^2) \; e^{-sx^{2}} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} x \Re \left( e^{-i(x^2-x)} - e^{-i(x^2+x)} \right) e^{-sx^{2}} \, dx \\
&= \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-(s+i)x^2 + ix} \, dx.
\end{align*}

By noting that

$$ z e^{-(s+i)z^2 + iz} = z \exp \left\{ -(s+i) \left( z - \tfrac{i}{2(s+i)} \right)^2 + \tfrac{i}{4(1-is)} \right\} $$

is an entire function with a nice vanishing speed as $ \left| \Re z \right| \to \infty$, we find that we can shift the contour of integration so that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x \sin \sqrt{x} \; e^{-sx} \, dx
&= \Re \left[ e^{\frac{i}{4(1-is)}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(x + \frac{i}{2(s+i)} \right) e^{-(s+i)x^2} \, dx \right] \\
&= \Re \left[ e^{\frac{i}{4(1-is)}} \frac{i}{2(s+i)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(s+i)x^2} \, dx \right] \\
&= \Re \left[ e^{\frac{i}{4(1-is)}} \frac{i}{2(s+i)} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{s + i}} \right].
\end{align*}

Taking $s \to 0^{+}$, we find that in Abel summation sense,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x \sin \sqrt{x} \, dx
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \Re \left( e^{\frac{i-i\pi}{4}} \right)
 = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \cos \left( \frac{1-\pi}{4} \right)
 = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sin \left( \frac{3\pi - 1}{4} \right)
\end{align*}

as desired.

Answer (score 6):

No, this integral is not convergent.

Consider $I(k):=\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x\sin \sqrt{2k\pi +x}dx$. For $k$ large enough, $\sqrt{2k\pi +x}-\sqrt{2k\pi}, x\in [0,\pi]$ is small enough, so

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x\sin \sqrt{2k\pi +x}dx\sim \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x \sin \sqrt{2k\pi }dx=2\sin \sqrt{2k\pi }\not\to 0.$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I was trying to follow what you have done. What does your integral say about the integral in the OP? I tried letting $x=y-2k\pi$ $\Rightarrow I(k)=\int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}{\sin(y)\sin\left(\sqrt{y}\right)}{dy}$, but I still don't see how this is related.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh If the integral $F(u)=\int_{0}^{u}$ converges in the strict sense, then $I(k)=F((2k+1)\pi)-F(2k\pi)\to 0$.

Comment: Sounds interesting, do you know the name for this or have a link abt it?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh If $F(u)$ conveges as $u\to \infty$, then $F(u)$ is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence

Answer (score 2):

The integral cannot converge since the function $\sin{x}\sin{\sqrt{x}} $ doesn't converge through zero as x tends to infinity

EDIT : There is a mistake, this proof if wrong. Read the comments

Comment: This answer may be correct but the reasoning is flawed. For instance, $\int_0^\infty \sin{(x^2)}\,dx$ does converge though $\sin{(x^2)}$ doesn't converge to zero when $x \to \infty$.